# How do I hide rows with duplicates between two excel files/workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help automating a daily task at work since I'm not a programmer. In short, I work with excel files and I am required to compare data between two workbooks for any duplicate values in any given columns (could be same or different columns) from both of the workbooks and hide the rows with the duplicate values in any one of those given workbooks. Since these workbooks are all different every time, is there a possible code that will allow me to hide the row with the duplicate values as needed on any workbook instead of me having to go through each row in every single workbook manually?

Comment: There is a "possible code" which you first try to write, and *then* we try to help.  You might also want to review your previous questions and consider accepting any answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a tool to consolidate different list, sheets or workbooks. From a 3rd workbook go to the "DATA" tab, and click on the "consolidate" button as shown on the Fig. 1. Then, click on the "Browse" button, select the first workbook and click "add" button. Then repeat the same with the second workbook.Finally clik on the 3 check boxes and press ok. Please find below a link to an explanation of the consolidate funtion. If the funtion does not reads from the workbooks, you can try copying the two sheets you want to compare in one worbook

[image: Fig.1]

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lk7HPyOHr0E